# relation "review_review" does not exist"

Tags: django

I am using  [django-review](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-review/1.8) package with one of my application where i am using the custom user model for Authentication. I have installed the django-review in my virtual environment and added the review app in my Installed_APPS as it is described in the documents of package.

but when i am running ./manage.py migrate review i am getting an error that **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "review_review" does not exist**
i did everythin same as it is defined in django-review package documents.

I am using django Version **1.6.5**

Comment: Which django version are you use? Add it to your question.

Comment: Please don't scatter-gun tags. This question has nothing to do with templates or views.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have run `./manage.py migrate` (or `./manage.py syncdb` on earlier Django versions).

Comment: No , it is not the reason, I have done both syncdb and migrate(for not synced) apps.